# How do I add index to a column in existing table?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to add MySQL `FULL TEXT SEARCH` index to an existing table `table1` to column called `tags`

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. It asks specifically about adding FULL TEXT SEARCH, not indexes in general.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when indexing with FULLTEXT indexes.

The default minimum word length is 4

MySQL has a list of words that are not imported into a FULLTEXT index. This list is called the stopword list

[Click here for the list of over 600 words excluded from FULLTEXT indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

This is what you must do before creating any fulltext indexes and bypass the stopwords:

Step 1) Create a stopword list with 'a','an','the'.

echo "a" > /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "an" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
echo "the" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt

Step 2) Add these options to /etc/my.cnf

ft_stopword_lfile=/var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt
ft_min_word_len=2

Step 3) service mysql restart

Step 4) Now, create the fulltext indexes you want.

If you created them already, drop them and create them again.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Also, FULLTEXT indexes are only available for the MyISAM storage engine, not for InnoDB

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX `idxtags` ON `table1`(`tags`)
```

Full syntax at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

Comment: I see you beat me by 20 sec. You got it!

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can imagine for doing that is because you have multiple tags stored in a single row. So I imagine your data looks something like this:

```
primary key    tags
--
1              tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4
2              tag1, tag5, tag7
3              tag4, tag13
```

Don't do that. Use a table of tags instead. Composite primary key would be (key, tag).

```
key    tag
--
1      tag1
1      tag2
1      tag3
1      tag4
2      tag1
2      tag5
2      tag7
3      tag4
3      tag13
```

Of course, since you didn't supply table structure or sample data, I could be completely off base. But based on the questions I read on SO every day, I'd be surprised.